# How can I make ng serve open in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, browser

I'd like to be able to serve my application to Edge but by default it opens in Chrome. This is what I see in .vscode/launch.json:

```
{
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "ng serve",
      "type": "pwa-chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/"
    },
    {
      "name": "ng test",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "preLaunchTask": "npm: test",
      "url": "http://localhost:9876/debug.html"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `.vscode/launch.json` file is only used for the debugging mood, so to make `ng serve --open` open with Microsoft Edge, you should change the default browser for your system to Microsoft Edge instead of Chrome

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work. I tried changing both types to variations of what you provided.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your question, I've updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

1. Download / install this edge plugin:
   https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/cors-unblock/hkjklmhkbkdhlgnnfbbcihcajofmjgbh
2. Run ng serve (no special args needed)
3. In the top right of your browser, click the plugin icon so it becomes yellow
   [image]
4. Right-click the plugin icon then select this option
   [image]

No more errors in console, page loads successfully!!!
[image]